# How is it possible that two deletes give a deadlock, if they do have different primary key data

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, delete

I am getting a deadlock by the same delete stored procedures that is called by two different threads for deleting two concurrent records.

The deadlock happened on the primary key index of the X table. 
Do you have any idea for solve this problem?

Here is the delete query:

```
DELETE FROM "MetadataContexts_data" WHERE iid=@iidvalue AND locked=@lockedvalue;
```

where *iid* and *locked* values for those two different delete are is *1845*, *2015-02-23T10:33:23:384.719* and *1846*, *2015-02-23T10:33:23:509.9806* respectively. 
There is no index on the *locked* column while *iid* is the primary key column.

Here is the deadlock graph: (table names obfuscated)

```
<deadlock-list>
<deadlock victim="process16a525c38">
    <process-list>
        <process id="process16a525c38" taskpriority="0" logused="1296" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594325368832 (d197ab30ed5e)" waittime="3108" ownerId="46495" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.617" 
        XDES="0x17305f378" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="6748" status="suspended" spid="53" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" 
        lastbatchstarted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.617" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.617" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.617" 
        clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="VL081" hostpid="7332" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" 
        xactid="46495" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_sidedata_delete" line="3" stmtstart="346" stmtend="644" sqlhandle="0x03000b001d519e72419502013aa4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    Delete  FROM &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot; WHERE &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot;.iid in (SELECT iid from Deleted)     </frame>
                <frame procname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_delete" line="9" stmtstart="608" stmtend="824" sqlhandle="0x03000b0098ac9718739bde003ba4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    DELETE FROM &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot; WHERE iid=@iidvalue AND locked=@lockedvalue;     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
    Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 412593304]    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process16a51d498" taskpriority="0" logused="1296" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594325368832 (5891aeb5d1b8)" waittime="3108" ownerId="46654" transactionname="user_transaction" 
        lasttranstarted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.653" XDES="0x16ac443a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="7556" status="suspended" spid="51" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" 
        lastbatchstarted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.653" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-23T11:33:23.653" 
        lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.653" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="VL081" 
        hostpid="7332" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="46654" currentdb="11" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_sidedata_delete" line="3" stmtstart="346" stmtend="644" sqlhandle="0x03000b001d519e72419502013aa4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    Delete  FROM &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot; WHERE &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot;.iid in (SELECT iid from Deleted)     </frame>
                <frame procname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_delete" line="9" stmtstart="608" stmtend="824" sqlhandle="0x03000b0098ac9718739bde003ba4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                    DELETE FROM &quot;MetadataContexts_data&quot; WHERE iid=@iidvalue AND locked=@lockedvalue;     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
                    Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 412593304]    </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594325368832" dbid="11" objectname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_data" indexname="2" id="lock16fabe080" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594325368832">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process16a51d498" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process16a525c38" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594325368832" dbid="11" objectname="DevDb.dbo.MetadataContexts_data" indexname="2" id="lock16fabd400" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594325368832">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process16a525c38" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process16a51d498" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Is any of those statements part of a bigger transaction?

Comment: These statements are both part of a trigger? I find it odd that one delete assumes there may be multiple rows affected by the trigger and the other statement seems to assume only one row is affected. Why are there two separate delete statements?

Comment: @spaghettidba No these are two completely different transactions

Comment: @AaronBertrand By the application logic there are multiple inserts and deletes happening. These inserts/deletes are not part of any trigger and from this delete sproc call exactly one row will be deleted.

Comment: I don't understand how there is no trigger involved yet there is `(SELECT iid from Deleted)`...

Answer (score 2):

You might be getting [lock escalation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323630).  This is when SQL Server replaces many fine-grained (row) locks with a single coarse-grained (table) lock to save system resources. This is most likely if you are processing many rows within a transaction.  That link suggests some work-arounds.